# Find matrix representation of transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two lines $l_1:y=x-3$ and $l_2:x=1$ find matrix representation of transformation $f$(in standard base) which switch lines each others and find all invariant lines of $f$

My attpempt is to choose $f$ to be rotation over $135$ degree so matrix of $f=A= \left[\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\end{array}\right]$
is it ok? and how to find invariant lines ?

Comment: It seems that OP has some confusion between linear and affine transformation. It's better to help to undertand or to  close?

Comment: Better to help in showing difference of the two.

Comment: @Jessy: If you want that the trnsformation switch the lies each others, a rotatin does not work. And note that also using a symmetry you have invariants lines (that are obviously the bisetrix and his orthogonal in $P$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Since the two straight lines intersect at the point $P=(1,-2)$  the transformation must have a fixed point in$P$. We can find such transformations in three steps.

1) translate the origin in $P$ with the translation $T_P^{-1}(x,y)\rightarrow (x-1,y+2)$

2) perform a simmetry $S$ with axis the strignt line passing thorough the new origin ad such that bisect the angle between the two lines.

3) return to the old origin with the translation $T_P(x,y)\rightarrow(x+1,y-2)$.

So the searched matrix has the form: $M=T_PST_P^{-1}$.

This is not a linear transformation but an affine one, and, if you want, can be represented by a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

If you have some problem to understand this I can help ...

---

Added after the comments.

The translation matrices in omogeneous coordinate are:
$$
T_P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&0&2\\
0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
T_P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&0&-2\\
0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the reflection matrix can be found noting that the angle between the bisetrix and the $x$-axis is $\theta=\dfrac{3\pi}{8}$, Then the matrix is:
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}\cos2\theta& \sin 2\theta&0\\ \sin 2\theta&-\cos 2 \theta&0\\
0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_rotations_and_reflections).

Note that the invariant lines are the bisector and his orthogonal in $P$.

Comment: I don't see what is for the simmetry $S$ can't I just replace point 2) by rotating matrix as here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations ?

Comment: OK I think I see the concept but have problem how to write it in matrices lanugege for instance $T^{-1}_p=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1\\0&1&-2\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]$ ?? and how to find simmetry matrix ?

Comment: I have added to my answer.